# how to call class in python for a program

Tags: python

The following code is throwing error from reading the values outside the class when calling. I can't make it!

```py
nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9

class Solution(object):
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        d = {}
        for i, n in enumerate(nums):
            m = target - n
            if m in d:
                return [d[m], i]
            else:
                d[n] = i
```

```sh
Error:
    nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9
           ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to literal
```

How to read the values of nums and target outside the class? Please explain. I am unable to figure it out.

It only works when I do this.

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
     s = Solution()
     print (s.twoSum([2,7,11,15], 9))
```

Why not the other way around -> nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9

Comment: You should use a semicolon instead of comma, or place the 2 assignments into separate lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nothing complicated but basic grammar.

```
nums, target = [2,7,11,15], 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just assign values on separate lines.
`nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9` is trying to assign 9 to nums AND trying to assign 9 to your list and target. The "cannot assign to literal" is due to it trying to assign the value 9 to the list. If you substituted a variable in-place of the list, it would then fail because the single value 9 couldn't be unpacked into two variables.

Answer (score 0):

Since the syntax part was dealt with by others, if you wanna use nums and target inside your class, remove the arguments nums and target from your class method definition like this:

```py
nums = [2,7,11,15]
target = 9

class Solution(object):
    def twoSum(self): # here is the change
        d = {}
        for i, n in enumerate(nums):
            m = target - n
            if m in d:
                return [d[m], i]
            else:
                d[n] = i

if __name__ == '__main__':
     s = Solution()
     print (s.twoSum())
```